# How to Detect Objects in the Image without using any library in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I am writing an application in `C++` that requires a little bit of image processing. Since I am completely new to this field I don't quite know where to begin.

Basically I have an image that contains a rectangle with several boxes. What I want is to be able to isolate that `rectangle (x, y, width, height)` as well as get the center coordinates of each of the boxes inside (18 total).

I was thinking of using a simple for-loop to loop through the pixels in the image until I find a pattern but I was wondering if there is a more efficient approach. I also want to see if I can do it efficiently without using big libraries like `OpenCV.`

Here are a couple example images, any help would be appreciated:

[image]

Also, what are some good resources where I could learn more about image processing like this.

Comment: The only image processing I've done was in collage where we had to find the most dominate color of an image, I used the [cimg library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) and I found it pretty comfortable.

Comment: If you have never done any image processing before please do yourself a favor and use OpenCV! There is little to be won if you repeat all the basic work like implementing matrix datatypes and all that.
Once you see that your algorithms work you can still try it without the external libs.

Comment: @Georg If you aren't doing this for commercial reasons, there's lots to be won: It's called learning.

Comment: @cbamber85 True that, but from my perspective there is still enough to learn about image processing to fill several lifetimes, even if you rely on other peoples code to do the grunt work. ;)

Comment: The qt tag seems irrelevant to the question, especially since Dave doesn't want to use "big libraries".

Answer (score 1):

The detection algorithm here can be fairly simple. Your box-of-squares (BOS) is always aligned with the edge of the image, and has a simple structure. Here's how I'd approach it.

1. Choose a colorspace. Assume RGB is OK for now, but it may work better in something else.
2. For each line

   1. For each pixel, calculate the magnitude difference between the pixel and the pixel immediately below it. The magnitude difference is simply sqrt((X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2+(Z-z)^2)), where X,Y,Z are color coordinates of the first pixel, and x,y,z are color coordinates of the pixel below it. For RGB, XYZ=RGB of course.
   2. Calculate the maximum run length of consecutive difference magnitudes that are below a certain threshold *magThresh*. You may also choose a forgiving version of this: maximum run length, but allowing intrusions up to *intrLen* pixels long that must be followed by up to *contLen* pixels long runs. This is to take care of possible line-to-line differences at the edges of the squares.
3. Find the largest set of consecutive lines that have the maximum run lengths above *minWidth* and below *maxWidth*.

Thus you've found the lines which contain the box, and by recalculating data in 2.1 above, you'll get to know where the boxes are in horizontal coordinates.

Detecting box edges is done by repeating the same thing but scanning left-to-right within the box. At that point you'll have approximate box centroids that take no notice of bleeding between pixels.

This can be all accomplished by repeatedly running the image through various convolution kernels followed by doing thresholding, I'd think. The good thing is that both of those operations have very fast library implementations. You do not want to reimplement them by hand, it will be likely significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it yourself (personally I'd use `OpenCV`, it's industrial-strength and free), you're going to need an edge detection algorithm first.  There are a good few out there on the internet, but be prepared for some frightening mathematics...

Many involve iterating over each pixel, and lifting it and it's neighbours' values into a matrix, and then convolving with a kernel matrix.  Be aware that this has to be done for every pixel (in principle though, in your case you can stop at the first discovered rectangle), and for each colour channel - so it would be highly advisable to push onto the GPU.

Comment: Since we're throwing ideas, do you think it makes since to have 4 threads that process each image starting from 4 corners?

Comment: If you mean split the image into quadrants, and restrict each thread to a quadrant - yes it will be 4 times faster.  But considering a GPU will give you orders of magnitude increases in performance, I wouldn't bother with the CPU at all.  And by using the `Thrust` library you could do this without having to learn OpenGL/OpenCL/CUDA.